# What does actually cdev_add() do? in terms of registering a device to the kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

What does `cdev_add()` actually do? I'm asking terms of registering a device with the kernel.

Does it add the pointer to cdev structure in some map which is indexed by major and minor number? How exactly does this happen when you say the device is added/registered with the kernel? I want to know what steps the `cdev_add()` takes to register the device in the running kernel. We create a node for user-space using `mknod` command. Even this command is mapped using major and minor number. Does registration also do something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read [Linux Device Driver](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/). It is a little bit old, but the main ideas are the same. It is difficoult to explain a simple operation like `cdev_add()` and all the stuff around in few lines.

I suggest you to read the book and the source code. If you have trouble to navigate your source code, you can use some tag system like etags + emacs, or the eclipse indexer.

Answer (score 13):

cdev_add registers a character device with the kernel. The kernel maintains a list of character devices under cdev_map

```
static struct kobj_map *cdev_map;
```

kobj_map is basically an array of probes, which in this case is the list of character devices:

```
struct kobj_map {
    struct probe {
        struct probe *next;
        dev_t dev;
        unsigned long range;
        struct module *owner;
        kobj_probe_t *get;
        int (*lock)(dev_t, void *);
        void *data;
    } *probes[255];
    struct mutex *lock;
};
```

You can see that each entry in the list has the major and minor number for the device (dev_t dev), and the device structure (in the form of kobj_probe_t, which is a kernel object, which represents a cdev in this case). cdev_add adds your character device to the probes list:

```
int cdev_add(struct cdev *p, dev_t dev, unsigned count)
{
    ...
    error = kobj_map(cdev_map, dev, count, NULL,
             exact_match, exact_lock, p);
```

When you do an open on a device from a process, the kernel finds the inode associated to the filename of your device (via namei function). The inode has the major a minor number for the device (dev_t i_rdev), and flags (imode) indicating that it is a special (character) device. With this it can access the cdev list I explained above, and get the cdev structure instantiated for your device. From there it can create a struct file with the file operations to your cdev, and install a file descriptor in the process's file descriptor table.

This is what actually 'registering' a character device means and why it needs to be done. Registering a block device is similar. The kernel maintains another list for registered gendisks.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code comments here:

> cdev_add() - add a char device to the system 464  *
>   @p: the cdev structure for the device 465  * @dev: the first device
>   number for which this device is responsible 466  * @count: the number
>   of consecutive minor numbers corresponding to this 467  *
>   device 468  * 469  * cdev_add() adds the device represented by @p to
>   the system, making it 470  * live immediately.  A negative error code
>   is returned on failure. 471  */ `

the immediate answer to any such question is read the code. Thats what Linus say.

[edit] 
the cdev_add basically adds the device to the system. What it means essentially is that after the cdev_add operation your new device will get visibility through the `/sys/` file system. The function does all the necessary house keeping activities related to that particularly the `kobj` reference to your device will get inserted at its position in the object hierarchy. If you want to get more information about it, I would suggest some reading around `/sysfs/` and `struct kboj`

Comment: Thanks for your reply!. Can you please elaborate your answer. I tried going through the kernel source code. It has some kobjmap structure... were we pass the dev_t and cdev structure..But I am not able to follow the source code well...Can you please explain me overview of this mapping process?

Comment: I have added more details to the answer as you requested. I somehow missed your comment until a new answer was posted.